# SharePoint Online : manage folder permission with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-online

I'm trying to write a Powershell script to grant user permission to a sub-folder in our SharePoint online site. I tried the solutions from the similar questions already open but without success.

I've got an online SharePoint site : https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/MySharePoint
In this SharePoint site I've got a library called Test which contains 2 sub-folders Test1 and Test2
I want the user "adtest@x.com" to be granted access to Test1 only in read/write (i.e. contributor).

I used the following code :

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL -Credentials $psCred 

$folder = Get-PnPFolder -URL "https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/MySharePoint/Test/Test1"

Set-PnPfolderPermission -list "Test" -identity $folder -User "adtest@x.com" -AddRole "Contribute"
```

When I run these commands, on the last step I get an error which translates as : "Impossible to find the level of authorization". My system is in French so I had to translate the message.

I tried the commands found from the other questions on the site but none worked.
Has anybody any idea on the issue ?

Thanks !
Fred

Answer (score 0):

In the pnp documention the identity is always the server relative path.

Try that, just use as identity:
"/Sites/MySharePoint/Test/Test1"

Comment: Thank you for your input but I'm still facing the same issue "Impossible to find the level of permission".

Answer (score 0):

try set the exact name of the permission role. Check it in the advanced permission level.
System need the name in french language resp. in the language of site collection, not english. [Example in slovak language  which i use](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uAgzJ.png)